# Automatically update date and time column from other date and time column

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I have a list of meetings where 2 of the columns are "Start" and "End" of type "Date and time".

Now I am trying to automatically update the "End" column after I add the date and time of the Start, but I want to still be able to edit it and I want the update to be asynchrone so it would update before submitting the new element form.

Do you have any ideas ?

Thank you for your response.

Comment: I think you mean "synchronous". You want the field updated before the form is submitted.  You will need to supply some more info... Classic or Modern UI? Which location? New form, Edit form, QuickEdit, All? Is a JavaScript solution OK?

Comment: To update "asynchronously" is easy with a simple workflow.

Comment: Yes, with asynchronously I meant that you don't have to reload the page or submit the form for the date to be updated. It would be for New form. Javascript is OK, and I use the classic UI, but what do you mean by "location" ? It's for a custom list.

Answer (score 0):

Use infopath to add a rule for the start field. set the end filed to be the Start add a certain time period. As a sample i set set it to be adding 5 days to start date. And you still can edit end time when you want. Every time you change start time field will update the end time.
[image]

Comment: Using Infopath isn't an option for my project. Isn't it possible to just use Javascript or make a C# script?

Comment: @AminosBoo Is workflow an option?

Comment: yes, a workflow is an option, but won't it then require to submit the form to see the update? I didn't find an event that could be useful in this situation.